# No visual feedback for hyperlink

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

In my code there is a hyperlink in a paragraph. While clicking on the hyperlink for the first time it shows a visual feedback(changes font) and it will navigate the page to Google home page.

If I come back to the page and click on the hyperlink again it doesn't shows the visual feedback but it navigates the page to Google home page.

How can I get visual feedback for every click?

```
<RichTextBox IsReadOnly="True"> 
<Paragraph> 
<Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://www.google.com" TargetName="_blank"> www.google.com  </Hyperlink> 
</Paragraph> 
</RichTextBox>
```

Comment: Try disable your hyperlink button on OnNavigatedFrom & enable it in OnNavigatedTo

Answer (score 0):

> Try disable your hyperlink button on OnNavigatedFrom & enable it in OnNavigatedTo
>
> Or remove hyperlink button from layout on OnNavigatedFrom and add it in OnNavigatedTo